# Finding the front Safari window using the ScriptingBridge and Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, safari, automator, scripting-bridge

I'm trying to get the URL of the front-most, active Safari window (Safari 5.2 running in Mountain Lion Developer Preview 2) through the ScriptingBridge, but can't find any property to determine if the window is the front one.

```
SafariApplication *safari = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.Safari"];
for (SafariWindow *window in safari.windows) {
    if ([window visible]) {
        // Top most, active window?
    }
}
```

This does not work — if I have two open Safari windows, both are `visible`.

Neither does using the `index` property of the `SafariWindow` nor the order of the windows array.

There is an Automator action called "Get current Webpage from Safari" that *does* work, so it should be possible, but I can't see how.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange you say the order of the `windows` array did not help, because it's supposed to: by definition, the "first" window is the frontmost one.  Also, Safari windows do not have URLs; they have tabs which have URLs.  Therefore, all you should need is this:

```
safari.windows[0].currentTab.URL
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use applescript

```
tell application "Safari" to get URL of front document
```

Comment: Yes, but the thing is, I need to do it via the Scripting Bridge and in Objective-C.

Comment: you can use NSAppleScript class.